# In what cases take operator is actually used?

Tags: rxjs

I would like to understand why `take` operator is used in code given below.

```
private _places = new BehaviorSubject<Place[]>(
// places for initialization
);

get places() {
  return this._places.asObservable();
}

addPlace(title: string, description: string, price: number)
{
    generatedId: string;
    newPlace: Place;
    // code to initialize newPlace
    return this.http.post<{name: string}>(
        'https://ionic-angular-ef2f8.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json', 
        {...newPlace, id: null})
        .pipe(
          switchMap(response => {
            generatedId = response.name;
            return this.places;
          }),
          take(1),
          tap(places => {
            newPlace.id = generatedId;
            this._places.next(places.concat(newPlace));
          })
        );
}
```

`post` request returns an `Observable`, and we get a value from it in `switchMap` operator (note that we do not `take` a value before calling `switchMap`). In `switchMap` we replace the observable with a new observable got from `_places`, a `BehaviourSubject` object. After `switchMap` we use `take` operator.
Why don't we skip `take` operator, and use `tap` straight off? Do we `take` a value from an observable, because the observable is generated from a subject? Who can explain the use case of `take` operator in details?

UPDATE

I suspect that the reason I should use `take` operator after `switchMap` is that `switchMap` returns an observable received from an object of type `BehaviorSubject` which holds emitted values. One can subscribe to such `BehaviorSubject` object and `take` the latest emitted value - that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 2):

`httpClient.post()` emits one `next` notification and one `complete` notification.

However, they're using `switchMap` to merge another Observable to the chain (`this.places`). `switchMap()` won't complete until its source and the inner Observable complete so they're using `take(1)` to complete the chain after the first emission from `this.places` which is a `BehaviorSubject` that doesn't complete until you deliberately call `complete()` on it.

This is a very similar use-case to using `takeUntil()` to complete chains. `takeUntil()` always has to be the last operator in a chain because completing a source Observable to `switchMap()`, `concatMap()`, ... doesn't necessarily complete the whole chain. See this for more details https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef

Comment: I know that `switchMap` replaces previous observable by a new one (it does not merge). I suspect that the first observable (received from `this.http.post`) is completed after `switchMap` worked.

Comment: I asked the question, because this code does not work without `take(1)` operator. I do not know why. (I unsubscribe the observable returned by `tap` in the code calling `addPlace` method)

Comment: Then maybe who calls addPlace() relies on its complete handler

Comment: No, it does not rely on it, it unsubscribes when its component is destroyed (I use `takeUntil` there).